# Finding stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm new to Windows servers and I have a hopefully quick question. I am looking for a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. I ran this query,

```
SELECT name, type
FROM dbo.sysobjects
WHERE (type = 'P')
```

Which returns a list of stored procedures. The one I am looking for is in the list. Now I need to know how/where to find this. I am browsing the structure on the left side and I see several folders of "Stored Procedures" but I do not see the item I am looking for in any of the lists. Is there SQL to show me the stored procedure or do I need to open it in SQL Server Management Studio? Could it also be a permission issue with the user I am connecting with?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Under the databases, I just have System Databases and Database Snapshots, I do not see my actual Database.. Which is where I thought the stored procedure would be. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does sound like a permission issue. Does this return anything for you?

```
use YourDatabaseName;
GO

sp_helptext 'YourSchemaName.YourProcedureName';
```

Comment: Yes, the sp_helptext does give me information back, it returns the procedure. However I cannot locate it under the Store Procedures and I need to edit it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @SkylerCain Change the "CREATE PROCEDURE" that was returned into an "ALTER PROCEDURE" and make your changes.

Comment: You are my hero of the day Joe. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can always see the content of the stored procedure using sp_helptext:

```
sp_helptext 'mystoredprocname'
```

You can also find the stored procedures by

1) Selecting your database and expanding it

2) Expanding the Programmability node

3) Expanding the Stored Procedures node

4) Searching through the list of stored procedures until you find the one you are looking for

Comment: Awesome, that helped so much. I can now see the procedure, what is the best way to update these stored procedures. Do I need to be able to see them under the Programmability node, because I do not see them there but I can run the sp_helptext and the other query to see it.

Comment: The easiest way is to navigate to the stored procedure in the left-hand navigation, right click on it, and select Modify. This will generate an Alter Procedure script in the Query window which you can then modify. When you are done with your modifications, you can press the Execute button to alter the contents of the stored procedure in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the query for this is:

```
select * 
from yourDB.information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

However if you do not see your DB its more then likely the user you are using doesn't have access.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

I am using this very handy extension which allows you to search and quickly find SQL in SQL Server Management Studio. You can quickly search for SQL text within stored procedures, functions, views etc. As for my writing it is free tool, have a look and learn more about it: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Answer (score 0):

We often follow the syntax:

```
create procedure procedureName
.........
```

If you did this your stored procedure will be created under the dbo schema of your database wherein you executed the create procedure script.

Now just in case if you wish to move your SP to a desired schema you need to modify your SP

```
alter procedure [schemaName].[USP_SP]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a script for that.
here it is:

```
--=====================================================================================
-- looking at all databases to find a stored procedure named @spName
-- marcelo miorelli
-- 1-april-2014
--=====================================================================================
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@spName VARCHAR(100) = 'usp_sel_CAEval4_comments' -- THE PROCEDURE THAT I AM LOOKING FOR

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
            SELECT CHAR(10) + ' UNION ALL '           + CHAR(10) +  
' SELECT ' + quotename(NAME, '''') + ' AS DB_NAME '   + CHAR(10) + 
'         , SCHEMA_NAME(s.schema_id)  AS THE_SCHEMA ' + CHAR(10) + 
'         , s.name  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS THE_NAME ' + CHAR(10) + 
'  FROM ' + quotename(NAME) + '.sys.procedures s ' + CHAR(10) +   
' WHERE s.name = @spName 
  AND s.[type] = ''P'''
            FROM sys.databases
            ORDER BY NAME
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '')

--PRINT @SQL

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL
    ,N'@spName varchar(100)'
    ,@spName
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to view a stored procedure's code::

sp_helptext name_of_your_sp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).